# Forwarding intents in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, forwarding, intentfilter

I am trying to capture audio/* mimetype action.View intents and forward them to another application (chosen by the user). The problem is that, while I am able, from a file manager, to select my Activity on file opening (through the app chosen dialog), I am not able to forward the intent to another activity (not the same one).
This is the manifest part about the activity:

```
        <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".TestMimeActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is the onStart code in the activity:

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I obtain only an infinite loop. I would like to open on the activity che app chosen dialog  (preferably without my app listed but I can also tolerate the whole list). Is it possible? How can I achieve this?

Thanks
Tobia Loschiavo

Comment: I'm a bit confused, your intent filter should be used to do what you are looking for. If you want to route different info to different activities the intent filter does that on its own.

Comment: From a file manager I want to open a file, then the action.VIEW intent is used with audio/* mimetype, then I want to open my activity selecting from the app chosen dialog and in my activity I want to reopen the app chosen dialog to send again the same intent (but chosing this time the music app for example). Starting the activity, I was expecting to have the chosen app dialog again but I have instead an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments above I think you are looking for [createChooser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29). You should modify your code to look like this:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select application"));
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if it is possible also to exclude my app from the list? I have seen also that the predefined flag is not present anymore...is it possible to have it?

Comment: Hmm I don't think so but it might be possible. Maybe post it as a new question. What do you mean predefined flag? the message?

Comment: no it's not possible, I guess that I have to recreate a custom chooser dialog with a list of apps (without mine and a checkbox at bottom) and store the selection somewhere. I think after a choice, the intent should be implicit no more but an explicit one. I think this is the solution.

Comment: A doubt remain...how to achieve the list of activities that can manage the intent...I will look into the android source code or ask a new question.